# Perform a search with LINQ and ignoring characters like î or ô or ê

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

In my DB I have some texts like this one: 'AVENUE GEORGES LEMAîTRE'. As you can see there is a ^ on the 'i' character.

Is it possible to perform a search with LINQ and ignoring this special character.

So I would like to search for **'AVENUE GEORGES LEMAITRE'** and find 'AVENUE GEORGES LEMAîTRE'.

```
var address = AddressRepository.Find(m => m.Street == "AVENUE GEORGES LEMAITRE").ToList();
```

Possible? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your database model to include a "canonical" version of `Street` along with the "actual" version that you display to or accept from the user. This canonical version could for example be all uppercase, with all diacritics removed, and normalized to a specific Unicode [normalization form](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html).

Assuming that you have a method `Canonicalize` that does this (this might be [a good place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)), you would invoke it when saving an address:

```
var address = /* incoming data */
address.CanonicalStreet = Canonicalize(address.Street);
/* save the model */
```

And you would also use it when retrieving data:

```
var street = "AVENUE GEORGES LEMAITRE";
street = Canonicalize(street);
var address = AddressRepository.Find(m => m.CanonicalStreet == street).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok so there is no other solution than 'cannonicalize' my street field? If not, then I prefer replacing all my î, ô, ê with i, o, e before saving to DB.

Comment: @Bronzato: That's just a more limited form of canonicalizing. If you do that without introducing a new column then the data will be visibly different from what the user previously entered, which is something to be avoided IMHO.

Comment: Yes but this is not really a problem in my project. Can you show me an example of canonicalize function as a starting point for me? Let's say for replacing all î, ô, ê by i, o, e ? Thanks.

Comment: @Bronzato: I already gave such a link -- "a good place to start".

Comment: Thanks. Your help was precious.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
List<String> address = (from ad in addressRepository where string.Compare("AVENUE GEORGES LEMAITRE", ad.Street.ToUpperInvariant(),CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0 select ad.Street).ToList();
```

Otherwise

This blog entry might help:

It details how to remove Diacritics from strings.

go to the bottom for the code sample.

Once the Characters are replaced the strings can be compared.

Hope this helps.

http://www.siao2.com/2007/05/14/2629747.aspx